# Is there a way of writing code similar to the syntax: class.method("variable").returnedVariable

Tags: c#

I am trying to improve my understanding of C#. Is there a way to write C# code in the format:

```
string name = Person("Dave").name;
int age = Person("Dave").age;
```

I know that this can be done in Javscript and I am aware this can be done in C# using a dictionary similar to:

```
int age = Person["Dave"].age;
```

or

```
int age = Person.age("Dave");
```

My understanding is that the dictionary option will just return a value and cannot run a method for get the value "age"

I have seen a few examples of code similar to the first two examples but do not understand how this would be written or if it is even possible.

Comment: Your first code block is valid C# provided that `Person` is a function that is called with an argument of `"Dave"`. Your second code block is valid C# provided that `Person` is a collection with an indexer, such as a Dictionary. Your third code block is valid C# provided that `Person` is an object and `age` is its member function that is called with an argument of `"Dave"`. So that all would be valid C#. And no, a dictionary can store whatever, not just built-in value types.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Within a dictionary you can store an entire object.

Comment: Thank you GSerg. Do you have an example of how the first example would be written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have such a syntax `Person("Dave").name` - you can implement a *helper*:

```
  namespace MyClasses {
    ...

    public static class PersonHelper {
      ...

      public static Person Person(string name) {
        //TODO: having name you should return Person instance, 
        // e.g. with a help of some dictionary:

        return Person.AllPersons.TryGetValue(name, out var result) 
          ? result
          : null;
     }
   }
```

Let's implement this `AllPersons` dictionary within `Person`:

```
   public class Person {
     // Simplest, but not thread safe
     private static Dictionary<string, Person> s_AllPersons = new
       Dictionary<string, Person>();

     public Person(string name) {
       // When Person created we put the instance into the dictionary
       s_AllPersons.Add(name, this);

       Name = name;
     }

     public string Name {get;} 

     public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Person> AllPersons => s_AllPersons;

     ...
   }
```

Then add `using static` to get rid of pesky `PersonHelper` name:

```
    using static MyClasses.PersonHelper;
```

And we've done:

```
    string name = Person("Dave").Name;
```

Here `Person("Dave")` will be treated as `MyClasses.PersonHelper.Person("Dave")` which return `Person class` instance for us of which we read `Name` property (or field)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this via Properties and a static Dictionary:

```
class Person {
  static public Dictionary<string, Person> Persons  {get; set;};

  public string Name {get; set; }

  public Person() 
  {
    if ( null == Persons ) Persons = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
  }
}

// Not tested, but shoud work
Person.Persons("dave")?.Name
```

But it will be not the same as in Javascript or in Python.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean: Person.Persons["dave"]?.Name; If i use  brackets i get "none invocable member cannot be used like a method"